# Does tar provide a method to tar up only files listed in a particular file?

Tags: linux, command-line, tar

The question title is pretty weird, but basically I have a file that is a list of other files, lets say `FilesIWantToTar.dat`. I want to say something along the lines of `tar -c --input-file=FilesIWantToTar.dat archive.tar` or similar. Does the `tar` utility provide this functionality, or do I need to write a simple script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

```
tar cf archive.tar -T FilesIWantToTar.dat
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I also read a little further and found the `--files-from=` option, equivalent to the `-T`

Comment: Yes, that's the long name.